# Should I put connection.close() on all finaly in java

Tags: java, database

Should I put **connection.close()** inside finally on try catch block? I tried to put connection.close() but i got and error "**java.lang.NullPointerException**"

here is the code on logging in is it Good to put **rs.close()** and pst.close() in every statement likeso below i insert it becuz if it is not there something pop up like database is locked..

***Login***

```
if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
        String sql = "select * from User_Table\n" +
                 "inner join Role_Table on User_Table.Role_ID=Role_Table.Role_ID\n" +
                 "where Username = ? and Password = ? and Role_Name = ?";
    try {
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
        pst.setString(2, jPasswordField1.getText());
        pst.setString(3, (String) RoleComboBox.getSelectedItem());

        rs=pst.executeQuery();
    if(rs.next()){
        String A = rs.getString("First_Name");
        String B = rs.getString("Role_Name");
    if(RoleComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Admin")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello "+B+" "+A,"Successfully Login",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        rs.close();
        pst.close();
        AdminPortal AP = new AdminPortal();
        AP.setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
    .... //and so on

    }else if(RoleComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Laboratorist,EO")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully Login");
        rs.close();
        pst.close();
    }}
    else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect Input","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }finally {
       try {
           rs.close();
           pst.close();
           conn.close();
       }catch(Exception e){

       }
    }
    }
```

here is the code on logout when I didn't put the **con.close()** there my system works fine but when i logout and login again it starts to got some error like database is locked but when I put the **con.close()"** i got some error "**java.lang.NullPointerException**"

***Logout***

```
int YesOrNo = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to logout?", "Logout",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if(YesOrNo == 0){
        try {
            dispose();
            LoginForm LF = new LoginForm ();
            LF.setVisible(true);
            AddPatient.getObj().dispose();
            AddAppointments.getObj().dispose();
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }finally{
            try{
                rs.close();
                pst.close();
                conn.close();
            }catch(Exception e){

            }
        }
    }else{

    }
```

i hope someone can help

Comment: Use try-with-resources.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no further use of the connection you can close it on finally block.

Comment: i got an error sayin java.lang.NullPointerException i already put the conn.close() in every finally on try catch block

Comment: kindly share the code for your error as there can be many cases in which NullPointerException can occur.

Comment: Null pointer generally occur when you are accessing the variable before the initialization.

Comment: or in your case it can be due to the fact that you close connection with your database, using con.close() in finally block and than after that you are again accessing the "con" variable elsewhere in your code.

Comment: again sharing your code will help a lot :-)

Comment: I added the codes now thank you

Comment: kindly upload your whole project on github and pass the link.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all types of connections should be  closed in finally block.

Comment: i got an error sayin java.lang.NullPointerException i already put the conn.close() in every finally on try catch block

Comment: close connection if there is no further use of that connection. i think in your case you closed before its final use.